# I want to get the time of a Sorting Algorithm, 5 sorting Algos, then compare each time on which is the fastest

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, comparison, stopwatch

I've coded this

```
 var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        _selection.ExecuteSelectionSorting(arr, true);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        sw1.Stop();
        elapsedMs1 = sw1.Elapsed.ToString();

 var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        _insertion.ExecuteInsertionSorting(ar, true);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        sw2.Stop();
         elapsedMs2 = sw2.Elapsed.ToString();

  var sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        _bubble.ExecuteBubbleSorting(number, true);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        sw3.Stop();
         elapsedMs3 = sw3.Elapsed.ToString();

  var sw4 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        MergeSort.MergeSort_Recursive(merge_input, 0, len - 1);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        sw4.Stop();
          elapsedMs4 = sw4.Elapsed.ToString();

         var sw5 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        QuickSort.QuickSort_Recursive(quick_input, 0, len_quick - 1);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        sw5.Stop();
        elapsedMs5 = sw5.Elapsed.ToString();
```

And I get it's time and displayed it on textboxes

```
 time1.Text = elapsedMs1 + " ms";
 time2.Text = elapsedMs2 + " ms";
 time3.Text = elapsedMs3 + " ms";
 time4.Text = elapsedMs4 + " ms";
 time5.Text = elapsedMs5 + " ms";
```

Now I want to compare this elapsed time on which is the fastest ...

```
double  sort1, sort2, sort3, sort4, sort5;
        // try
        //{
             sort1 = Convert.ToInt32(time1.Text);
            sort2 = Convert.ToInt32(time2.Text );
            sort3 = Convert.ToInt32(time3.Text);
            sort4 = Convert.ToInt32(time4.Text);
            sort5 = Convert.ToInt32(time5.Text);

            if (sort1 > sort2 && sort1 > sort3 && sort1 > sort4 && sort1 > sort5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Algorithm is Insertion Sort", "Result",
                                      MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else if (sort2 > sort1 && sort2 > sort3 && sort2 > sort4 && sort2 > sort5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Algorithm is Selection Sort", "Result",
                                      MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else if (sort3 > sort1 && sort3 > sort2 && sort3 > sort4 && sort4 > sort5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Algorithm is Bubble Sort", "Result",
                                      MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else if (sort4 > sort1 && sort4 > sort2 && sort4 > sort3 && sort4 > sort5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Algorithm is Merge Sort", "Result",
                                      MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            }
            else if (sort5 > sort1 && sort5 > sort2 && sort5 > sort3 && sort5 > sort4)
            {
     MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Algorithm is Quick    Sort", "Result");
```

This is the thing that I've done so far and I'm kinda lost... 
Thanks for your help guys T_T

I always get the error of Converting DateTime to Int you need to Parse something like that

Comment: Why on Earth are you converting the time to string in the first place?

Comment: Why not sort the times instead of this if-else-abomination?

Comment: Why are you waiting 500 ms after each algo run?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `double sort1, sort2, sort3, sort4, sort5` to `long sort1, sort2, sort3, sort4, sort5` and `Convert.ToInt32` to `long.Parse`

You should probably keep track of your elapsed time variables somewhere globally or within the class and not work through the textboxes to access them though.

Comment: I've tried this and it won't work too...I change my time1.textbox to the elapsedms1 on the class but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

There are about a million ways to do it. I'll give you just a clue to the conversion problem, but yout algorithm needs a good refactoring.

Instead of define your sort1..sort5 as double, define them as Timespan:

```
TimeSpan sort1,sort2,sort3,sort4,sort5;
```

And then, convert your textboxes values like this:

```
sort1 = DateTime.Parse(time1.Text).TimeOfDay;
sort2 = DateTime.Parse(time2.Text).TimeOfDay;
```

And so on...
After that, you can compare your sort values as you please :)

**Edit**
As it throws you an error, although i've tried above code and works just fine, try this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
sort1 = DateTime.ParseExact(time1.Text.Trim(),"hh:mm:ss.fffff",provider).TimeOfDay;
```

**Edit 2**
This is a working (at least in my computer) code sample:

```
var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
string elapsedMs2 = sw2.Elapsed.ToString();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
string elapsedMs3 = sw2.Elapsed.ToString();
sw2.Stop();
TimeSpan s1 = DateTime.Parse(elapsedMs2).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan s2 = DateTime.Parse(elapsedMs3).TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Thank you so much .... I'm so new to c# and people like you is one great help for human beings like me T_T. Thank you so much. I will try your suggestion ^_^

Comment: it won't work T_TWhen converting a string to DateTIme
, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the date time object

Comment: I don't understand.It gives you any error? Or are the results not what you expected?

Comment: Yes, the error is "When converting a string to DateTIme , parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the date time object " :(

Comment: I think that could be a problem with your locale datetime format. Can you paste an example date you see in your textboxes?

Comment: It's 00:00:00.51099 < just an example :) >

Comment: Try my edited answer. But as i explain there, i've tried my code and works fine, don't know why it does not work to you.

Comment: I got the same error over and over again T_T Can I know how did u code your stopwatch ?

Comment: See my updated answer. It's the sample i've used and works just fine. Try it and if it works, compare it with your actual code to see where the error is.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much... I'm so sorry if it's hard for me to comprehend T_T glad there's someone like you

Comment: Don't worry, glad to help.